# Why are my site's Google Webmaster Tools index status and URLs submitted statistics different?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

On the dashboard of my site where it shows sitemap I see 18 URLs submitted, 9 URLs indexed.

However under Index Status it shows Total Indexed: 0, Ever Crawled: 332.

What does this mean, why are the indexed figures different?

**For clarity**: The site has been online since 14th Feb and my sitemap was created using Drupal XML Sitemap which was submitted straight away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dashboard index status indicates status for image files as well, so that number is usually higher.

The index status should be displaying at least one page, I would be worried about this one. Go on google and type the following site:yourwebsite.com and see how many pages are returned. You'll have a better idea of what's indexed.

Also, the data changes over time. You can always create a new sitemap and submit it if there were changes to your website.

Take a look under html improvements as well, see if there are pages with the same meta description and/or title.

Comment: In hindsight that is exactly what I did, so because of that upvote and accept!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you created the right Sitmap.xml for your website and placed in right place as you mentioned in Google Webmaster.

I highly recommended to use Scram-Frog seo spider (If you website contend below 500 pages) or use Xenu link sleuth software to create your .XML sitemap.

Answer (score 0):

all these data change over time, I'd suggest waiting week or 2

Answer (score 0):

Just normal, this stats are not up to date, delayed for round about a week.